# populate dictionary with for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several large dictionaries where all the values are the same except for the last several characters.

like : `http://www:example.com/abc`

Right now im using a dictionary like so:

```
categories = {1:'http://www:example.com/abc',
              2:'http://www:example.com/def'
```

with an additional 30 k,v pairs.

How can I use a for loop to add the static and end variables together as the value, and generate integer as keys of a dictionary?

`static = 'http://www.example.com`

`end = ['abc','def']`

Comment: If you want integers as keys, why not simply use a list?

Comment: @mkrieger1 To be completely honest I didn't even think about it. I wish i had before I spent 20 minutes thinking about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you are trying to do with a dictionary comprehension.

```
static = 'http://www.example.com/'
end = ['abc','def']

{ k:'{}{}'.format(static, v) for k,v in enumerate(end) }
```

But it does beg the question as raised by @mkrieger why not just use a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary comprehension.

```
template = 'http://www.example.com/{path}'
categories = {i+1: template.format(path=e) for i, e in enumerate(end)}
```

Since the keys are a range of integers, you could as well use a list. The only difference is that the indices start at 0 instead of 1.

```
categories_list = [template.format(path=e) for e in end]
```